# Passing item value from model to JS - MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

Im working on a project with MVC and i'd like to know if there's a way to store the id of an input, which is a value received from one of my model items, into one of my JS variables

here's how the id of the input is being adressed

```html
@foreach (var item in Model) {

<input type="hidden" value="@item.id" id="@item.id">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.nome" id="@item.nome">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.preco" id="@item.preco">

}
```

and here's what i been trying to do in my .JS file

```js
var id = document.getElementById('@item.id').value;
var nome = document.getElementById('@item.nome').value;
var preco = document.getElementById('@item.price').value;
```

Comment: Store where? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just need to store the ID of those inputs into my variables on javascript, but those ids are dynamically changed as they are coming from my one of my model classes

Answer (score 1):

You can use css class to mark elements where you want to store the id

1. select all elements with that css class using js
2. read id attribute for each element using loop
3. store it the way you need, eg. an array

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you try this you see that your values are saved.

```
let id = document.getElementById('Id').value;
let name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
let price = document.getElementById('Price').value;
console.log(id);
console.log(name);
console.log(price);
```

but i somehow fail to use them in html. This doesn't work for example.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('Id').innerHTML = id;
    document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('Price').innerHTML = price;
</script>
<h1 id="Id"></h1>
<h1 id="Name"></h1>
<h1 id="Price"></h1>
```

It's maybe because the input is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Well you can just expose that item ID directly to JavaScript

```html
<script>
// this must be in the .html file, using window makes the variable global
// most rendering frameworks don't do conditional/server side rendering on static js files
window.ITEM_DATA = {
    itemId: "@item.id"
}
</script>

<input type="hidden" value="@item.id" id="@item.id">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.nome" id="@item.nome">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.preco" id="@item.preco">
```

### Method 2

Alternatively, you can give each input a class and select all of the classes (or all of the inputs with type hidden)

```html
<input type="hidden" value="@item.id" id="@item.id" class="item-data">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.nome" id="@item.nome" class="item-data">
<input type="hidden" value="@item.preco" id="@item.preco" class="item-data">
```

```js
// this could be in its own file because we aren't relying on the server
// this is client-side js
const [itemId, itemNome, itemPreco] = document.querySelectorAll(".item-data")
// this could also fit a narrow use case
// document.querySelectorAll("input[type='hidden']")
```

Edit: added clarification to method 2

Answer (score 0):

you can access model directly in razor page like @ModelName.objectname but you should import model like
@model ModelName
example : @Model.id